# Generate multiple tests based on a function's output

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytest

I have a function (`my_plots()`) that creates and displays multiple figures with `matplotlib`.  I want to test these figures using the `pytest-mpl` plugin, which appears to need a single figure per test.
https://github.com/matplotlib/pytest-mpl

By using `monkeypatch` I can generate a sequence of figures (`get_figures()`) and pass these through `pytest.mark.parametrize`.  This works for the actual image comparison but, because I'm running the original function outside the test, it is unaffected by other useful `pytest` features such as `pytest.mark.filterwarnings` (or any fixtures I add).

Is there a better way to generate the tests?

```
import warnings

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytest


def my_plots():
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0, 1])
    plt.show()
    
    plt.figure()
    warnings.warn("bad things may happen")
    plt.plot([0, 2])
    plt.show()
    

def get_figures():
    def no_show():
        pass
    
    with pytest.MonkeyPatch.context() as mp:
        mp.setattr(plt, "show", no_show)
        my_plots()
        
    for fig_num in plt.get_fignums():
        yield plt.figure(fig_num)
        

@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("error")        
@pytest.mark.mpl_image_compare
@pytest.mark.parametrize("fig", get_figures())
def test_my_plots(fig):
    return fig
```

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue https://github.com/matplotlib/pytest-mpl/issues/133

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/pytest-mpl/issues/133#issuecomment-1031428664), here is the best I've come up with so far.  Note I can't use the `monkeypatch` fixture within the `get_figures` fixture because [it has a narrower scope](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/363).

```
import warnings

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytest


def my_plots():
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0, 1])
    plt.show()
    
    plt.figure()
    warnings.warn("bad things may happen")
    plt.plot([0, 2])
    plt.show()
    

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def get_figures():
    def no_show():
        pass
    
    with pytest.MonkeyPatch.context() as mp:
        mp.setattr(plt, "show", no_show)
        my_plots()
        
    figs = [plt.figure(fig_num) for fig_num in plt.get_fignums()]
    return figs
        

@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("error")        
@pytest.mark.mpl_image_compare
@pytest.mark.parametrize("fig_index", [0, 1])
def test_my_plots(fig_index, get_figures):
    return get_figures[fig_index]
```